# Why isn't my buffer working?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redpower

I'm sorting items into barrels. Since items are coming from BC pipes, sometimes two barrels would be allocated the same thing, so I put in a buffer, however the whole thing has stopped flowing. Before there was just pneumatic pipe where the buffer was. What have I done wrong?

[image]

Inputs are the BC pipes. They feed into a relay, which outputs to pneumatic. This then feeds through a buffer (to collect up stacks) and then out the pneumatic and to my barrels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you've got the wrong Buffer. All the RedPower Buffer does on its own is store items. Each input side corresponds to 5 separate inventory slots, but the output side has access to all 25 of them. It doesn't output on its own.

You may be confusing it with the Buffer from the add-on mod [TubeStuff](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1001131-146-immibiss-mods/), which accepts items and sends them on as stacks, one every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Ejector (crafted like a Relay but with redstone instead of red doped wafer) and have it pulsed with a timer.

This allows stacks to form before they are sent out into the tube network.